# How to make navigation link to expandable list in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to make navigation links to an expandable list.
I want to make navigation links only to sub-lists like "UICollectionView", "UIScrollView", "NavigationView", and "Expanding Rows".
But I don't know how to deal with this problem.
If someone helped me, I would appreciate it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TutorialItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    var tutorialItems: [TutorialItem]?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let tutorialItems: [TutorialItem] = [sampleUIKit(), sampleSwiftUI()]
        
        List(tutorialItems, children: \.tutorialItems){
            tutorial in
            
                    Text(tutorial.title)
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


func sampleUIKit() -> TutorialItem {
    return .init(title: "UIKit", tutorialItems:
                    [.init(title: "UICollectionView"),
                     .init(title: "UIScrollView")])
}

func sampleSwiftUI() -> TutorialItem {
    return .init(title: "SwiftUI", tutorialItems:
                    [.init(title: "NavigationView"),
                     .init(title: "Expanding Rows")])
}
'''
```

Comment: I think you mean a DisclosureGroup. It is another SwiftUI View. It is like a Section but expanding.

Comment: If you want to use UIkit views inside SwiftUI , You have to use UIViewRepresentable !

Answer (score 0):

I tried and below worked for me

```
    @State var favItems = [BookmarkItem]()
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            List {
                ForEach(favItems) { item in
                    Section(header: Text(item.title)) {
                        OutlineGroup(
                            item.bookmarkItems ?? [],
                            id: \.id,
                            children: \.bookmarkItems
                        ) { tree in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("-- \(tree.desc)")) {
                                Text("\(tree.desc)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

//BookmarkItems

```
struct BookmarkItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var bookmarkItems: [BookmarkItem]?
}
```